# Чем отличается ArrayList ArList = new ArrayList();

Tags: java, arraylist, коллекции

от Collection collection = new ArrayList();

Comment: 1ArrayList...ArrayList();   2Collection...ArrayList();

Comment: ммм.... то есть дженерики не брать в учет?

Comment: да, я имел ввиду чем отличается написание в начале arrayList или Collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сравнивая

```
ArrayList ArList = new ArrayList();
```

и

```
Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

мы найдем небольшие различия:

- `new ArrayList()` это тоже самое что `new ArrayList<Object>()`
- Для `ArList` типом ссылки будет тип [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- А для `collection` типом ссылки будет интерфейс [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), от которого созданы все коллекций: списки, ассоциативные массивы, множества.

Более подробно вы узнаете из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/index.html).

Comment: Т.е. использование Collection дает нам просто больше методов?

Comment: Дает только общие для всех коллекций методы, а специфичные (для список, массивов и т.п.) не будут доступны для ссылки. Если понадобится вызвать методы списка, придется привести collection к типу ArrayList